# Can I refreeze raspberries in cooking?

Tags: frozen

I have frozen raspberries in the freezer. Can I defrost them and use them in muffins...and then freeze some of the muffins?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

just be careful, thawing the raspberries will make them more mushy and release more water.

Comment: Just a tip: I get better results by adding the frozen berries without thawing them, that way they don't get mushy in the batter. You may have to bake a little longer.